# What are the guiding principles when practicing TDD?

Tags: tdd

This is supposed be an open question but I would like the answer to focus more on code design aspects.

To help narrow the scope of the answer:

- How do you decide if a class should be a concrete class or an interface that is mocked when it's not so obvious.
- What's your experience of allocating roles and responsibilities.
- To what dependency depth do you typically go to.
- How much of the already perceived target design influences the tdd process.
- What's you experiences of making a tdd driven implementation fit within pre-existing code.
- any other design consideration.

Thanks!

Comment: Narrowed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncle bob defined [the three laws of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd):

- You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
- You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
- You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

Following the classic Red-Green-Refactor cycle, remember about [the four rules of simple design defined by Kent Beck](http://xprogramming.com/classics/expemergentdesign/). Apply them during the refactor phase. The code must (in priority order):

- Run all the tests
- Contain no duplicate code
- Express all the ideas the author wants to express
- Minimize classes and methods

Comment: An important extension I heard of - before the 3rd law you also add: "you are not allowed to write production code until the test fails in a readable way". This way you make sure that if somewhere in the future the test will fail, you're guaranteed to have a clean and readable message, not just an arbitrary exception.

Comment: Well, that's more related to the way you write tests. If you write tests-first the feedback is in my experience very good. It's easier to achieve if you treat writing tests as a design activity. I'm glad you brought it up though, 'cause that leads to another interesting topic related to tdd - test smells. Worth reading about!

Comment: Yes, but if you follow the rule "You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail;" you're left with a test failing in as simple way as possible (usually an exception, or a failed assert with not-always-helpful message).

Answer (score -1):

The 0th law of TDD:

Break the TDD process whenever it is too tedious, [motherfucker](http://programming-motherfucker.com/)!

How do you know that TDD is too tedious? When you regularly write tests in
5 minutes, and it suddendly takes you more than one 8 hour shift to write
those tests for that part, which calls 3rd party something, then it is too
tedious. Forget unit tests and test it manually from time to time. The goal
is to have 95% covered, not 100%.

Comment: I think I will disagree here @Boris :) the point behind tdd is not just to produce working code it is also to (1) show how the API works, (2) allow for more freedom in refactoring code, (3) help write testable code. So it may get tedious for some but I think well worth the effort.